# How many bits does an enum value need?

Tags: c++11

```
#include <stdint.h>

enum state : uint8_t {
    NONE,
    USA,
    CAN,
    MEX
};

struct X {
    state st : 2;  // compiles with uint8_t st : 2
};
```

Clang 3.9.0 compiles successfully.

GCC 4.8.4 and 5.3.0 complain with:

```
warning: ‘X::st’ is too small to hold all values of ‘enum state’
```

Who is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**Both are correct.**

---

The value of an enumeration is limited by the underlying type, *not* by the enumerators!

C++14, 7.2 Enumeration declarations, paragraph 8:

> It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators.

Which means it is possible to:

```
state x = static_cast< state >(5);
```

That is what GCC is warning you about: `enum state` could have values that do not fit into 2 bits.

However, as long as you don't try to actually *do* that to `X::st`, everything is shiny.

That's (probably) why Clang is *not* warning you about it.

Since the standard does not demand a diagnostic either way, there's nothing wrong about warning, or not warning you.

Comment: Drat! Guess I need `uint2_t` :(

Comment: @Bulletmagnet: Just don't specify an underlying type for the enum, and use `uint8_t` in the struct. You could still `X x = state::MEX;`, and you would not get a warning.

Comment: Alas, I actually started using `enum class`, which generates the warning even without specifying the underlying type :(